# What are the modifications required on dts file to migrate from 5inch MIPI DSI display to 10.1 inch MIPI DSI display on imx8 board?

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, device-tree, imx8

I am trying to bring up 10.1 inch mipi dsi display with compulab ucm-imx8mp board. The development board will work with default 5 inch mipi display. Now I wanted to change the display size to 10.1 inch. The 10.1 inch display has same pin configurations as 5 inch display.
Please guide me on, what are the major changes I need to perform on my ucm-imx8m-plus.dts file to make this 10.1 inch display work?

The below changes I have made so far, please review it and give your inputs.

[10.1' display timing parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx15k.png)

modified ucm-imx8m-plus.dts for 10.1' startek mipi display

```
&mipi_dsi {
    status = "okay";
    panel: panel@0 { 
            compatible = "startek,kd101wxfid025";
            reg = <0>;
            reset-gpio = <&pca9555 4 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
            dsi-lanes = <4>;
            status = "okay";
            clock-frequency = <67000000>;
            hactive = <1280>;
            vactive = <800>;
            hback-porch = <38>;
            vback-porch = <10>;
            hfront-porch = <16>;
            vfront-porch = <8>;
            hsync_width = <4>;
            vsync_width = <4>;
    };
};
```

The startek display controller IC is ILI9881C. And the mipi host controller driver is imx_sec_dsim_drv. I have added 10.1' startek display serial number also in ili9881c driver code as below,

```
static const struct of_device_id ili9881c_of_match[] = {
{ .compatible = "startek,kd050hdfia020" },
{ .compatible = "startek,kd101wxfid025" },
{ }
};
```

Is this right way of bring up this 10.1' startek display? Any input on this would be really helpful.

Comment: Please edit your post to add the current part of the dts file related to the display.